# when creating a release version I get the following warnings (vs 2008 settings)

Tags: c++

warning lnk4075:ignoring /editandcontinue due to /opt:icp specification

error lnk2005: initp+misc_invarg already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)

i have many more errors lnk2005 all int he libcmt.lib file in the invarg.obj

also 
lnk2098:: defaultlib conflicts with use of other libs.

when i had it as debug it was all working
i just started to make a release and everything went south. could I get some help how to do the release version

the lib i was using is a composite lib which was working with my test app. however before i do the final release i wanted to test the release version of my lib but when i include that into my test app i got the aforementioned errors

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're mixing up runtime versions. Make sure all of your projects are built with either the Multithreaded C Runtime, or the Multithreaded DLL C Runtime. If you mix the two linking will fail.

Comment: so here is the problem. I started a whole new application with default settings. then changed it to release and made sure i am compiling it with /MT as i did the static lib. 

I added my static lib to test which was created from the release version. 

when i include it but just copying the file to the project and build it i get
lnk1181 cannot open input file. even though I made sure its in the linker under additional dependencies. Not sure why it can't find it?

Comment: @djones2010: I have no idea what you're trying to tell me in that comment. If you're getting more error messages of a different type, post the **exact** error message you are receiving as part of your question. Your "almost the same" translations are not sufficient for us to research the actual error you are receiving.